# Add extra dimension to an axes

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, tensorboard

I have a batch of segmentation masks of shape `[5,1,100,100]` (`batch_size x dims x ht x wd`) which I have to display in tensorboardX with an RGB image batch `[5,3,100,100]`. I want to add two dummy dimensions to the second axes of the segmentation mask to make it `[5,3,100,100]` so there will not be any dimension mismatch error when I pass it to `torch.utils.make_grid`. I have tried `unsqueeze`, `expand` and `view` but I am not able to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post your attempts with the mentioned functions, and why exactly they didn't work (maybe an error message etc.)? Also, do you expect there to be the same values in all three dimensions, or simply zeros for every other dimension?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `expand`, `repeat`, or `repeat_interleave`:

```py
import torch

x = torch.randn((5, 1, 100, 100))
x1_3channels = x.expand(-1, 3, -1, -1)
x2_3channels = x.repeat(1, 3, 1, 1)
x3_3channels = x.repeat_interleave(3, dim=1)

print(x1_3channels.shape)  # torch.Size([5, 3, 100, 100])
print(x2_3channels.shape)  # torch.Size([5, 3, 100, 100])
print(x3_3channels.shape)  # torch.Size([5, 3, 100, 100])
```

Note that, as stated in the docs:

- [`torch.expand()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.expand):

> **Expanding a tensor does not allocate new memory**, but only creates a new view on the existing tensor where a dimension of size one is expanded to a larger size by setting the stride to 0. **Any dimension of size 1 can be expanded to an arbitrary value without allocating new memory**.

- [`torch.repeat()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.repeat):

> Unlike `expand()`, **this function copies the tensor’s data**.

Comment: How about repeat_interleave? Does it require new memory, or does it perform a strided view similar to expand?