# How to compute pairwise distance between point set and lines in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

The point set `A` is a `Nx3` matrix, and from two point sets `B` and `C` with the same size of `Mx3` we could get the lines `BC` betwen them. Now I want to compute the distance from each point in `A` to each line in `BC`. `B` is `Mx3` and `C` is `Mx3`, then the lines are from the points with correspoinding rows, so `BC` is a `Mx3` matrix. The basic method is computed as follows:

```
D = torch.zeros((N, M), dtype=torch.float32)
for i in range(N):
    p = A[i]  # 1x3
    for j in range(M):
        p1 = B[j] # 1x3
        p2 = C[j] # 1x3
        D[i,j] = torch.norm(torch.cross(p1 - p2, p - p1)) / torch.norm(p1 - p2)
```

Are there any faster method to do this work? Thanks.

Comment: hi @Berriel, thanks for comment. Yes, the lines are from corresponding rows between B and C. I've updated the post. Thanks.

Comment: Note that if you don't provide `dim` to `torch.cross`, it will use the first `dim=3` which would give the wrong results if `N=3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the `for` loops by doing this (it should speed-up at the cost of memory, unless `M` and `N` are small):

```py
diff_B_C = B - C
diff_A_C = A[:, None] - C
norm_lines = torch.norm(diff_B_C, dim=-1)
cross_result = torch.cross(diff_B_C[None, :].expand(N, -1, -1), diff_A_C, dim=-1)
norm_cross = torch.norm(cross_result, dim=-1)
D = norm_cross / norm_lines
```

Of course, you don't need to do it step-by-step. I just tried to be clear with the variable names.

**Note**: if you don't provide `dim` to `torch.cross`, it will use the first `dim=3` which would give the wrong results if `N=3` (from the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.cross)):

> If dim is not given, it defaults to the first dimension found with the size 3.

If you are wondering, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56952901/4228275) why I chose `expand` instead of `repeat`.